# Ionic Framework Button Not Showing

Tags: ionic-framework

The following button icon at the side menu is not showing...

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
          <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
    </ion-pane>

    <ion-side-menu side="left"></ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons won't show because you'll have to use them inside the `<ion-view>`tag and inside `<ion-nav-buttons>` tag.

See the following example from the Ionic Framework Documentation ([link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavButtons/))

```
<ion-nav-bar>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
      <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">
        I'm a button on the primary of the navbar!
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
      Some super content here!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code as below. Thanks!!!

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <ion-nav-buttons>
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
  </ion-pane>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable menus with logic:

```
<ion-menu id="NavMenu" persistent="true" [content]="content">
```

Be sure you haven't got some code like this hanging around!

```
import { MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';
...
constructor(
   private menuCtrl: MenuController
) {

}

...

// In some other method..
// When you only have one ion menu in the template....

this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'NavMenu');
```